# What is the correct syntax for webpack command line options?

Tags: webpack, command-line-interface, documentation, webpack-cli, node-commander

I've seen two in the docs ...

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

> version 1

```
webpack --mode=development
```

and

https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/

> version 2

```
npx webpack --mode development
```

One has the equal sign and one does not.  If they are both correct, which is preferred?

Comment: This is rather a question of `commander` since `webpack-cli` uses that. Their readme does seem to indicate that they are the same. As to which one is better, well... there could be multiple opinions about that.

Comment: Kind of annoying that they switch back and forth in the docs ... would be nice if they picked one or the other for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no difference between 2 of those and both are correct.

Without *webpack-cli* you cannot execute both variants.
The only difference between those examples is whether *webpack-cli* was installed as a global package.
If you previously installed it with *-g* flag then the first option (without *npx*) is available, otherwise you can always use 2nd option.

Comment: So which version does webpack-cli enable?  the first our the second? Q updated.

Comment: webpack-cli package is required for both.

0) if you do not have this package installed, then both options will not work.

1) If you installed webpack-cli package as 'npm install -g webpack-cli', then 1st option is possible

2) If you installed webpack-cli package as 'npm install webpack-cli', then 2nd option is possible inside a folder containing package.json